# Wordpress staging environment and premium plugins

Tags: wordpress, staging

I have a client who wants some quite core changes made to her wordpress site. I want to makes these changes on a staging temp domain, I was going to export and and import using All-In-One WP Migration as I've used it before and it all worked fine. However this site has some premium plugins installed, does anyone know if copying the site to a staging area will mess up the plugin registration etc?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: I think most premium plugins are activated with a licence key, so provided that carries across I don't see it being an issue.

Comment: Thanks Sam, so they don't check that it's being used twice and disable one or anything? Thanks again

Comment: Good question - I wouldn't like to say for sure. You might be better contacting the developer of the plugins in question to ask them.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks, I have via twitter and have been waiting a while. I can't get onto the support part because I didn't buy the plugin and hence don't have an account with them, fun fun fun!

Comment: Yep, been there. Well, if you were to set up the staging site on MAMP/WAMP I don't imagine the plugin will break as it won't count as being on a separate live site.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea.